# Not FInding String Match With Contains- Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, java-stream

running into a problem.
The code is not finding the string that **equals 8QQ** which is a match
here is my full code.

```
            String selector = "div#companyIdBarCompListGrid_rows_scrollpane table tbody tr[id*=companyIdBarCompListGrid_] td span div a";
            int links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(selector)).size();
            System.out.println("Number of links: " + links);

            // begin inner for-loop
            for (int i = 0; i < links; i++) {
                PP_OBJ_CycleData.ScrollToTop(driver);// scroll up

                List<WebElement> CCTable = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(selector));
                WebElement code = CCTable.get(i);           
                System.out.println("\n"+code.getText().substring(0, 3).trim()+"\n");
                //code.click();

             //----------------------checking for bad code -----------------------------------------
                String[] badcodes = {"8QQ", "8BQ", "8JQ"};
                boolean check = Arrays.asList(badcodes).contains(code);
                System.out.println(check);
                //check == true will work as well
                if(check){
                    System.out.println(check+"Bad Code found breaking loop");
                    break;
                }else{

                    //checking to make sure element is clickable
                    PP_OBJ_CycleData.isClickable(code, driver);
                    System.out.println("Clickable?"+ code.isEnabled());
                    code.click();   
                }
```

I think the problem is this part here:

```
List<WebElement> CCTable = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(selector));
                WebElement code = CCTable.get(i);           
                System.out.println("\n"+code.getText().substring(0, 3).trim()+"\n");
                //code.click();
```

I am cutting off everything but the first 3 characters with sub string but that is during the print statement. however **the string is actually longer or has more characters than what is in the array for 8QQ.** Could this be the problem if so is there a way to get around it? So that it **only tries to match the first 3 characters?** the.contains() is not doing it i don't think.

I saw matches.find() methods but have not had any success.

---

This is my code now it works had to think about it for a long time my code is below. and now it breaks loop.

```
                    String selector = "div#companyIdBarCompListGrid_rows_scrollpane table tbody tr[id*=companyIdBarCompListGrid_] td span div a";
                    int links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(selector)).size();
                    System.out.println("Number of links: " + links);

                    // begin inner for-loop
                    for (int i = 0; i < links; i++) {
                        PP_OBJ_CycleData.ScrollToTop(driver);// scroll up

                        List<WebElement> CCTable = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(selector));
                        WebElement code = CCTable.get(i); 
                     // changing code to mcode to look for first 3 characters    
                        String mcode = code.getText().substring(0, 3).trim();
                        System.out.println("\n"+ "modified "+ mcode);
                       // System.out.println("\n"+code.getText().substring(0, 3).trim()+"\n");

                     //----------------------checking for bad code -----------------------------------------
                        String[] badcodes = {"8QQ", "8BQ", "8JQ"};
                        boolean check = Arrays.asList(badcodes).contains(mcode);
                        System.out.println(check+"code in array list");
                        //check == true will work as well
                        if(check){
                            System.out.println(check+"-Bad Code found breaking loop");
                            break;
                        }else{
                            //checking to make sure element is clickable
                            PP_OBJ_CycleData.isClickable(code, driver);
                            System.out.println("Clickable?"+ code.isEnabled());
                            code.click();   
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code

1. `Arrays.asList(badcodes)` returns a List<String>, while `code` is a WebElement: you're comparing two different types, so `check` will never be true
2. You say that `code` is more than three characters, but List.contains expects equality.

You might be confusing String.contains and List.contains.

[myString.contains(code)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) will return true if `code` *is a substring* of the String `myString`
[myList.contains(code)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) will return true if `code` *is an element* of the List `myList`

In your code, `Arrays.asList(badcodes).contains(code)` calls List.contains, and returns false because - as you say - `code` is longer than any of the Strings you're comparing to.

How do you fix it?

1. Convert `code` to a String. You should know how to do that, because you already do it in the System.out.println above.
2. Ensure `code` has the same length as the strings you're comparing to. You should know how to do that, because you already do it in the System.out.println above.